# Android Studio strange replace with for each suggestion

Tags: android

Can any one got any clue what was Android Studio intention in the next scenario?

I got this piece of code:

```
    for (Fragment fragment : getChildFragmentManager().getFragments()) {
        if (fragment instanceof DashMenuFragment && selectedId != -1) {
            ((DashMenuFragment) fragment).setSelected(selectedId);
        }
    }
```

The `getChildFragmentManager()` is marked with yellow suggestion mark, saying:

[image: Can be replaced with foreach call]

When I agree and tell it to use the suggestion my code become this:

```
    getChildFragmentManager().getFragments().stream().filter(fragment -> fragment instanceof DashMenuFragment && selectedId != -1).forEach((Fragment fragment) -> {
        ((DashMenuFragment) fragment).setSelected(selectedId);
    });
```

### WHAT IS THIS?

Comment: nothing supported on android. The Stream api is available on Java 1.8

Comment: Mb in your project settings for the language level support your have "8"? I'm not sure if this is possible in AS though (as compared to Intellij), chances are it's hidden.